# Доступ к сайтам, запущеным с VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

На VirtualBox стоит Debian 6 64х-битная и настроен сервер, сайты и прочее. 
Задача, чтобы при открытии сайтов с винды, они вытягивались с виртуальной машины
Помогите настроить. Весь день мучаюсь, не получается.

Answer (score 3):

Если для сетевого подключения используется NAT, нужно пробросить порты, тогда при открытии в браузере адреса localhost:8080, будет открываться сайт, запущенный в виртуальной машине на порту 80.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Где-то статью находил, сейчас уж не вспомню, но по статье получил следующие настройки:

В настройках сети (в VB в свойствах машины) ставим **Attached to "Bridged adapter"**

**Adapter type** стоит **PCnet-FAST III**

Еще вроде как надо гостевые дополнения поставить.

Апач соответственно надо настроить не на локалхост, а на полученный адрес.

В настройках домашней ОСи ip получаю динамически, но ставил и статический.

Лучше погуглить - там точнее скажут)

Comment: [Вот сслыка](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/vm/VirtualBox-networking.html) - там расписаны все режимы сети